# Getting daylight saving time info for a network connected "embedded" device

Tags: datetime, embedded, ntp

I'm developing a device that is connected to a home network.
The device is getting current timestamp (in seconds) from a local Unix machine in the network.
I'm using NTP protocol and I'm getting 64-bit UTC timestamps.

To convert a UTC timestamp to a local time, I need local UTC offset and daylight saving time info. My local UTC offset is known but the info whether being in daylight saving time or not is not readily available.
What I found from my search is that it can be determined from the month/day, which is derived from the UTC timestamp, TZ info, and local daylight saving scheme.
It can be done but it is quite a cumbersome process and the device needs to carry and maintain the daylight saving info.

Because the device is connected to a Unix machine and Unix machine knows if it is in daylight saving time or not.

So, I'm wondering if there is a way to figure out if a Unix host is in a daylight saving time by using a network protocol, instead of figuring out by itself.
I don't want to write a telnet client and ask 'date' or '$TZ'.
I prefer much simpler, ideally with UDP. I can parse returned message if the message contains a hint.

I thought about writing my own UDP server just returning the info. But I prefer not to do so as it is proprietary and not portable.

My application doesn't need to follow daylight saving time rigorously. Missing the first one hour or so doesn't matter.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Best regards,
Aki Niimura

Comment: It seems no easy way to get daylight saving time info from a Unix machine (unless you write a proprietary UDP server to provide such info), I decided to implement a software routine to check if it is in DST or not.

Comment: I found that the routine won't be so complex *if* it only supports current daylight saving scheme in the US (most areas). However, it still took longer than the system can tolerate. I pre-calculated many items in the equation to speed up. I still prefer to use a network protocol to figure out if it is in DST as my current solution is not portable. But for now I'm okay with what I implement.
BTW, validating the routine was quite tricky.